# If statemen in the wrong place

Tags: php, mysql

Please you help? I run a query via search form and output results, although, it is not displaying as it should? Still new to php so please excuse if my code is....

the result needed. If te search returns I want one of 2 things. To either show Employed by: xxx or Not currently employed:

```
 <?php
if ($_REQUEST['submit']) {

$term = $_POST['term'];

$row ['employerid'] == $user_data ['user_id'];
$XX = "<br><br><div class='messagebox'><h2> <center> Oops! </h2> <p>We were only to retrieve a partial record on <strong>$term</strong>  you have entered. Please make use of our contact form if you would like us to get you your reference. Be sure to enter the three required fields.  <a href='Mailforms/refrequest.php'  class='lightbox'>Click Here!</a> or to validate the id <a href='idverification.php'> Click here</a></p>
<br />


</div>";  

 $sql = mysql_query("select * from ref_employees where   `idnumber`= '$term'")
   or die('Error in query : $sql. ' .mysql_error());

{

if (mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0  ) 
{            

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

    if ($row ['employed'] == '1') {
    echo '<h4>Currently Employed By :   '.$row['companyname'];
    echo '</h4> ';}

    if ($row ['employed'] == '0') {
    echo '<h4>Not Currently employed :   '.$row['companyname'];
    echo '</h4> ';}





    echo '<h4>  ID                  :  '.$row['idnumber'] ;
    echo '<br>  First Name          :  '.$row['firstname'];
    echo '<br>  Last Name           :  '.$row['lastname'];
    echo '<br>  Gender              :  '.$row['gender'];

    echo ' </h4>';


    echo '<br />';
    echo '<h2>Some Additional Options</h2>';
    echo '<br />';


}
}
else
 {
print ("$XX");
}
mysql_free_result($sql);
mysql_close($connection);
}
```

Comment: Above `if (mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0  )` you have `{` remove it, also there is no need for `mysql_free_result($sql);` if you're closing the connection right after it, that is only usable if you're going to make other queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have put an extra opening curly brace `{` above `if (mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0  )  {`
Corrected Code:

```
<?php
if ($_REQUEST['submit']) {

$term = $_POST['term'];

$row ['employerid'] == $user_data ['user_id'];
$XX = "<br><br><div class='messagebox'><h2> <center> Oops! </h2> <p>We were only to retrieve a partial record on <strong>$term</strong>  you have entered. Please make use of our contact form if you would like us to get you your reference. Be sure to enter the three required fields.  <a href='Mailforms/refrequest.php'  class='lightbox'>Click Here!</a> or to validate the id <a href='idverification.php'> Click here</a></p>
<br />
</div>";  
$sql = mysql_query("select * from ref_employees where   `idnumber`= '$term'")
   or die('Error in query : $sql. ' .mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0  )  {
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    if ($row ['employed'] == '1') {
    echo '<h4>Currently Employed By :   '.$row['companyname'];
    echo '</h4> ';}

    if ($row ['employed'] == '0') {
    echo '<h4>Not Currently employed :   '.$row['companyname'];
    echo '</h4> ';}
    echo '<h4>  ID                  :  '.$row['idnumber'] ;
    echo '<br>  First Name          :  '.$row['firstname'];
    echo '<br>  Last Name           :  '.$row['lastname'];
    echo '<br>  Gender              :  '.$row['gender'];

    echo ' </h4>';


    echo '<br />';
    echo '<h2>Some Additional Options</h2>';
    echo '<br />';


}
}
else
 {
print ("$XX");
}
mysql_free_result($sql);
mysql_close($connection);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I would like that should the employed = 0 then the part where it says Currently employed by should not display at all :) Thanks again

Comment: My apologies to all, cache issues. Thanks to all replies. You guys are the BEST!